# TensorFlow: tf.one_hot with varying on_values

Tags: tensorflow

I want that the depth can be a tensor so that this is the result:

indices = [0, 1, 2], depth = [4,1,2]

tf.one_hot(indices, depth)

Result: [[4., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 2.]]

Comment: How would you write this in numpy?

Comment: Solved It! Posted an answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up solving it:

```
A = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[4])
depth = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[4])
oneHots = tf.one_hot(A, 4, dtype=tf.int32)
result = tf.multiply(oneHots,tf.transpose(depth))
```